# openssl got different DH public key on php and c

Tags: php, c, openssl

I want to implement key exchange between php and c, but the secret computed by DH_compute_key on both language always mismatch, so I digging a little into the detail and found that it seems openssl generated different key on different language.

I expected the DH public key generated by same parameter and private key should be the same, but I got different value on php and c.

here is the php code:

```
$dh_param = array(
    "dh" => array(
        "p" => hex2bin("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC90FDAA22168C234C4C6628B80DC1CD1"
            . "29024E088A67CC74020BBEA63B139B22514A08798E3404DD"
            . "EF9519B3CD3A431B302B0A6DF25F14374FE1356D6D51C245"
            . "E485B576625E7EC6F44C42E9A637ED6B0BFF5CB6F406B7ED"
            . "EE386BFB5A899FA5AE9F24117C4B1FE649286651ECE45B3D"
            . "C2007CB8A163BF0598DA48361C55D39A69163FA8FD24CF5F"
            . "83655D23DCA3AD961C62F356208552BB9ED529077096966D"
            . "670C354E4ABC9804F1746C08CA18217C32905E462E36CE3B"
            . "E39E772C180E86039B2783A2EC07A28FB5C55DF06F4C52C9"
            . "DE2BCBF6955817183995497CEA956AE515D2261898FA0510"
            . "15728E5A8AACAA68FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"),
        "g" => "2",
        "priv_key" => hex2bin("581268c890b5cf1a4924f74f1a7f5b160949bde05133ef4bd1bcc89792c37c00"
            . "f20166d63ef442196e7f663c3ffd8e927ff7ed1f140079c1fbb069a127435a2c"
            . "2e0476ae185f6526db3c7a818cd3106d43fd1befc30925fcdccc658ebfdd1b21"
            . "6311844cdf674076a14e490d761b6328c978753ef20283b50a251dc06b2f7966"
            . "b626d202707bb9ab49c12b7d7e32bbe78b17a73ba1ceaa118088e5dcc58f3226"
            . "8650342a7b2baf3372f993d15bd663934a6015f7e066ddd7575b70819dda6e8d"
            . "6b1468f418dc13744cffd6f80ef259e26e247ba49c97b658776e64b76aec421b"
            . "083ec4b2f68045cf310f3cb245354a6a1ad2c76915d7a83ff18b126665039de5")
    )
);

$dh = openssl_pkey_new($dh_param);
$dh_detail = openssl_pkey_get_details($dh);
echo substr(bin2hex($dh_detail['dh']['pub_key']), 0, 10), "\n";
```

the output is: `a0a4ad686e`

and c code:

```
const char *p_hex =
        "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC90FDAA22168C234C4C6628B80DC1CD1"
        "29024E088A67CC74020BBEA63B139B22514A08798E3404DD"
        "EF9519B3CD3A431B302B0A6DF25F14374FE1356D6D51C245"
        "E485B576625E7EC6F44C42E9A637ED6B0BFF5CB6F406B7ED"
        "EE386BFB5A899FA5AE9F24117C4B1FE649286651ECE45B3D"
        "C2007CB8A163BF0598DA48361C55D39A69163FA8FD24CF5F"
        "83655D23DCA3AD961C62F356208552BB9ED529077096966D"
        "670C354E4ABC9804F1746C08CA18217C32905E462E36CE3B"
        "E39E772C180E86039B2783A2EC07A28FB5C55DF06F4C52C9"
        "DE2BCBF6955817183995497CEA956AE515D2261898FA0510"
        "15728E5A8AACAA68FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";

const char *priv_key_hex =
        "581268c890b5cf1a4924f74f1a7f5b160949bde05133ef4bd1bcc89792c37c00"
        "f20166d63ef442196e7f663c3ffd8e927ff7ed1f140079c1fbb069a127435a2c"
        "2e0476ae185f6526db3c7a818cd3106d43fd1befc30925fcdccc658ebfdd1b21"
        "6311844cdf674076a14e490d761b6328c978753ef20283b50a251dc06b2f7966"
        "b626d202707bb9ab49c12b7d7e32bbe78b17a73ba1ceaa118088e5dcc58f3226"
        "8650342a7b2baf3372f993d15bd663934a6015f7e066ddd7575b70819dda6e8d"
        "6b1468f418dc13744cffd6f80ef259e26e247ba49c97b658776e64b76aec421b"
        "083ec4b2f68045cf310f3cb245354a6a1ad2c76915d7a83ff18b126665039de5";

DH *dh = DH_new();
BN_dec2bn(&dh->g, "2");
BN_hex2bn(&dh->p, p_hex);
BN_hex2bn(&dh->priv_key, priv_key_hex);
DH_generate_key(dh);

const char *pub_key_hex = BN_bn2hex(dh->pub_key);
printf("%.10s\n", pub_key_hex);
```

the output is `1606378B62`

I have study source code of php openssl extension, the c code above should have same behavior.

Comment: Each run of the protocol produces different ephemeral public keys. If everything is working properly, then they will never be the same.

Comment: but if I run those code multiple times, I always got same public key for each lang, isn't it related to private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well...
I spend a lot of time to check the prime and private key,
but they are all fine.

the bug is on the generator, it should be binary 2, not ASCII "2".

just change parameter to `"g" => hex2bin("02")` and it works fine